# Use Viber behind proxy on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, proxy, viber

I want to use viber on my 16.04 LTS ubuntu system in my job.
Is this possible? Can I use the viber behind proxy?
Do someone know like this?

Comment: Seems like Rakuten wants to control the connection at both ends due to their own encryption. I have found no way to bypass or connect through our proxy although Skype works on our systems. The network admins have to create the tunnel and set up firewall rules for Viber, to allow the traffic.  Good luck with that request. Also, over VPN, Viber does not work correctly - THAT, I believe is Rakuten's intention; although it could just be my VPN provider.

Comment: I wanted to tell I set it up in /etc/environment but still get no connection... so that's why. Thank you both for the answer.